# Get local currency in swift

Tags: xcode, swift, locale, currency

I am setting up an little in app purchase store for muliple countries. How can I figure out that I have to show up the price in Dollar, Euro etc...
I think it have to do with the localeIdentifier but I am not sure how to handle this

Answer (score 78, accepted):

You can get the currency symbol and code from `(NS)Locale` with

**Swift 1 and 2**

```
let locale = NSLocale.currentLocale()
let currencySymbol = locale.objectForKey(NSLocaleCurrencySymbol)!
let currencyCode = locale.objectForKey(NSLocaleCurrencyCode)!
```

**Swift 3**

```
let locale = Locale.current()
let currencySymbol = locale.object(forKey: .currencySymbol)!
let currencyCode = locale.object(forKey: .currencyCode)!
```

**Swift 3.1+**

```
let locale = Locale.current
let currencySymbol = locale.currencySymbol!
let currencyCode = locale.currencyCode!
```

This correlates with the user region format settings and works in both `iOS` and `macOS`

Comment: With Xcode beta 4 (Swift 3) I'm getting the error: Value of type 'Locale' has no member 'object'

Comment: @blwinters i think the swift 3 equivalent is Locale.current.regionCode

Comment: @blwinters The syntax can change all the time during the beta period. Please read the documentation of `Locale` in the appropriate Xcode version.

Comment: @vadian Okay, I see here (https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nslocale) that currencyCode is now a property of Locale and object(forKey:) is no longer available, or at least isn't tagged 'Beta'.

Comment: Also `Locale.current()` becomes `Locale.current`. :)

Answer (score 9):

for swift3

```
//User region setting return
let locale = Locale.current //NSLocale.current

//Returns true if the locale uses the metric system (Note: Only three countries do not use the metric system: the US, Liberia and Myanmar.)
let isMetric = locale.usesMetricSystem

//Returns the currency code of the locale. For example, for “zh-Hant-HK”, returns “HKD”.  
let currencyCode  = locale.currencyCode

//Returns the currency symbol of the locale. For example, for “zh-Hant-HK”, returns “HK$”.
let currencySymbol = locale.currencySymbol
```

Answer (score 1):

For iOS 16+

```
//Returns the user's current locale
let locale = Locale.current

//Returns the local currency's symbol
//Ex: $
let currencySymbol = locale.currencySymbol!

//Returns the currency code of the locale. Returns nil if the data isn't available
//Ex: USD
let currencyCode = locale.currency!.identifier
```